# Tableau: How to display size as the number of records for the same lat,long

Tags: geolocation, size, latitude-longitude, tableau-api

On the same (lat,long) on a Tableau-Desktop map, I want the size of a dot  to be proportional to the number of records at that location. I tried count/sum(Number of Records) built-in tableau measure, I created a SeqId and tried count(SeqId) for Size, neither worked. Here is a sample of my data, as you can see:
(44.92810490,-74.89186500) has one Record
(44.69948730,-73.45291240) has five Records
(44.72143010,-73.72375280) has 10 records
I would like the point to be proportional to the number of records at that location.   Help is Much appreciated
Musa
Seq Id,Census,Gender,Lat,Long
1,1860,F,44.92810490,-74.89186500
2,1870,M,44.69948730,-73.45291240
3,1870,F,44.69948730,-73.45291240
4,1870,M,44.69948730,-73.45291240
5,1870,F,44.69948730,-73.45291240
6,1870,F,44.69948730,-73.45291240
7,1870,M,44.72143010,-73.72375280
8,1870,M,44.72143010,-73.72375280
9,1870,M,44.72143010,-73.72375280
10,1870,M,44.72143010,-73.72375280
11,1870,M,44.72143010,-73.72375280
12,1870,M,44.72143010,-73.72375280
13,1870,M,44.72143010,-73.72375280
14,1870,M,44.72143010,-73.72375280
15,1870,M,44.72143010,-73.72375280
16,1870,M,44.72143010,-73.72375280

Comment: Treat latitude and longitude as dimensions in this case, although you may also want to round them with a calc

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

- Create a calculated field "Geo" with this definition
  `IFNULL(STR([Lat]),"")+ ","+IFNULL(STR([Long],"")`
- Move this field in "size" mark using `Count([Geo])`

Hope this should give you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

- Put Latitude on the Rows shelf, and then right click on the pill and convert it to a dimension. Make sure it stays continuous.
- Likewise, put Longitude on the Columns shelf and convert it to a dimension
- Put SUM(Number of Records) on the size shelf
- Important, Don't have any other dimensions on any shelves, leave SeqId off

This approach will make one mark for each unique latitude/longitude pair and size that mark according to how many times that pair appears in the data set.

A problem you will probably notice is that two latitudes that differ only in the final decimal place are treated as distinct latitudes. That may not make the most useful visualization. You can bin nearby latitudes together by making a calculated field to round values to the degree you wish. If you do that, be sure to make your field a continuous dimension, and also set its geographic role. It has the effect of snapping lat/long pairs to a grid. As an alternative to rounding, you can look into the hexbinx() and hexbiny() functions.

For a heat map based on square or hex grids, you may want to try using (partially transparent) colors instead of size to indicate density.

Comment: Thanks Alex, it works. Although it is a work around, I do not see the wisdom of not supporting something like this directly in tableau.

Comment: Glad to help. Welcome to Stack Overflow. If the answer solved your problem, its customary to accept the answer and upvote it.